# Page header style question

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

[image: Header Style]

I am curious of how I can make this header style as shown in the picture? It looks nice to me. Thank you so much!

The following is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{
 left=1.30in,
 right=1.30in,
 }

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{stmaryrd} 
\usepackage{lmodern, enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

Trying to make a new header style.

\end{document}
```